# Is it possible to use web development tools and create an actual working WYSIWYM math editor, like desktop Applications such as MathType?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, wysiwym

Before I started to try and make this thing, I wanted to know if it is possible, under the following circumstances:

- The code to script up that math must be able to be taken, submitted and stored in a database
- The code for two pieces of math which look exactly the same must have the exact same code
- According to the requirements, wherever the user clicks his or her mouse, the caret must move to that specific element or part of the math

So, is it possible? I'm looking forward to using technologies such as HTML, JavaScript, jQuery, and even Flash as a last resort.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: @shhac Thank you once more for the suggestion. I've used that, but I couldn't find any editing features. It is just for static Math equation display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**MathQuill**](http://mathquill.com/) lets you type maths in a WYSIWYG fashion, source [**here**](https://github.com/laughinghan/mathquill).
There is a demo on the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like MathML. Take a look here. http://www.w3.org/Math/

or maybe http://code.google.com/p/mathmleditor/

Comment: actually, thanks for the suggestion, but MathML won't work. It only works well for static math equations, not WYSIWYM ones.

Comment: actually, a rather hard-to-answer one. If anyone could find an already-made working online math editor that I could use, it would be even better.

Comment: You could also make a calculator in a java applet and load it in a webpage, that would be the easy way out :)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not into Java, so I don't know how to make one. Could you help by finding one online or something?

Comment: Yes I know. That's the problem. Also, the MathMLEditor would be compliant if I was working with a bunch of LaTeX or MathML nerds. Unfortunately, I'm not. That's why it has to be WYSIWYM.

Answer (score 0):

I found this a while ago http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php pretty useful implementation of LaTeX with a live preview, I've used it a few times. Probably doesn't fit the bill for your point 3 either but just in case it is useful.